# Cloud Function Update Problem in Firestore Database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to build an Android application. In my Firestore database I have Users collection and Counters collection. In Counters collection I have userCounter. What I want to do is whenerever a new user logs in and I push it to firestore, userCounter to increase.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.addNewUser = 
functions.firestore.document('Users/{userID}').onCreate((event) => {

var db = admin.firestore();
var counterRef = db.collection("Counters");
var temp = counterRef.doc("0").data().userCounter++;

counterRef.doc("0").update(
{
    userCounter: temp
});
});
```

In this state, this function doesn't work, and I'm a newbie so I'd appreciate any help.
Thx beforehand

**EDIT**

After implementing Firebaser and Pablo Almécija Rodríguez's answers, my code looks like this.

```
const Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const firestore = new Firestore({
  projectId: process.env.GCP_PROJECT,
});
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.addNewUser =
functions.firestore.document('Users/{userId}').onCreate((snapShot) => {

  const userCounterRef = db.collection('Counters').doc('Users');

  return db.runTransaction(transaction => {

   const doc = transaction.get(userCounterRef);

    console.log("1");
   const count = doc.data();
    console.log(`5`);
   const updatedCount = count + 1;
    console.log(`6`);
   return transaction.update(userCounterRef, {counter: updatedCount })
  })
});
```

And this is the firebase console log. The problem is

```
const count = doc.data();
TypeError: doc.data is not a function
```

[Firebase Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3Wfy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to create a collection named counters and inside it a document named users to handle counter for users. Here is the structure:

```
- counters (collection)
  - users (document)
    count: 0 (field)
```

Then, you should use a transaction to perform an update on this counter document to make sure you are working with up-to-date data to deal with concurrency (multiple accounts created at the same time)

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.addNewUser = 
functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}').onCreate((snapShot) => {

  const userCounterRef = db.doc('counters/users');

  return db.runTransaction(async transaction => {
   const doc = await transaction.get(userCounterRef)
   const { count } = doc.data()
   const updatedCount = count + 1
   return transaction.update(userCounterRef, {count: updatedCount })
  })
});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

EDIT: If you don't want to deal with async/await syntax, update your transaction like that :

```
return db.runTransaction(transaction => {
     return transaction.get(userCounterRef)
     .then(doc => {
         const count = doc.data().count
         const updatedCount = count + 1
         transaction.update(userCounterRef, {count: updatedCount })
     })

})
```

Comment: Thait is exactly why I'm trying do this counter update in cloud functions :) So I deleted async and await since it is Android and firebase deploy --only functions gave error on those two. But still it doesn't increment the counter when there is a new Users document. What do I need to write in place of {userID}?

Comment: {userId} is a wildcard, you don't have to change anything here.
and what is the problem with Android ? cloud functions works on their own side. You may share your compiling errors to see what's going wrong

Comment: Sorry I was confused, what meant to say I'm writing in JavaScript rather than Android and I saw that async await is for TypeScript, I may be wrong.

Comment: You're getting this error because you've removed the async/await syntax so your function is no longer asynchronous.. I've updated my code with the classic promise. Async/Await is just an ES6 feature and it's not related to typescript.

Comment: np you can mark it as selected answer to help other people

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced it in Cloud Functions, and this simple solution worked. **Edited** answer to fit Firebase, and it also uses the [Firestore dependency](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.20.x/) for nodejs.

```
const Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const firestore = new Firestore({
  projectId: process.env.GCP_PROJECT,
});

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
//I am not using next two lines right now though
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.helloFirestore = 
functions.firestore.document('users/{userID}').onCreate((event) => {


  const doc = firestore.doc('Counters/UserCounter/');
  doc.get().then(docSnap => {
    //Get the specific field you want to modify
    return docSnap.get('userCount');
  }).then(field => {
    field++;
    //Log entry to see the change happened
    console.log(`Retrieved field value after +1: ${field}`);
    //Update field of doc with the new value
    doc.update({
      userCount: field,
    });
  });
});
```

The wildcard you used should be fine, just be careful with the full path for the collection, mind the upper/lower case. For this case, this is how my **package.json** looks like:

```
{
  "name": "sample-firestore",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/firestore": "^1.1.0",
    "firebase-functions": "2.2.0",
    "firebase-admin": "7.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it's me but doc.get() AND }).then(field lines get error in npm while deploying.

Comment: I edited my answer. I am using now both firebase-functions and google-cloud/firestore dependencies to fit Firebase Cloud Functions.